# Unable to locate the model you have specified error in linuxmint

Tags: php, codeigniter, pointers, models, linux-mint

I have been trying to load the model usersModel.php but I have no luck of going through that error
I have checked my codes more than a dozen times and I can't seem to find the error in it.
At school, my code is working. I think it's because I am using windows 10 OS in the library, but when I get home and try it on my machine it always shows the error above. I can't seem to understand

Here is the code of my controller:

```
class Login extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
        }    
    function validate(){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|callback_checkuser');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'md5|trim|required');
        $x = $this->form_validation->run();
        if($x){
            if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') == 1){
                $this->load->model('balancesModel');
                $this->balancesModel->b1_update();
                $this->balancesModel->b2_update();
                $this->balancesModel->b3_update();
                redirect((base_url()) . 'admin/tenants');
            }else{
                redirect((base_url()) . 'main/payments');
            }
        }else{
            $x['title'] = "CPMS - Login";
            $x['error'] = "incorrect username/password";
            $this->load->view('startpage', $x);
        }
    }

    function checkuser(){
    $this->load->model('usersModel'); //this part is where the error starts
        $x = $this->usersModel->get_user();
        if($x){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code of my usersModel:
I have tried so many tutorials to locate the model but nothing seemed to work for my code

```
class UsersModel extends CI_Model{  
        function get_user(){
            $username = $this->input->post('username');
            $password = md5($this->input->post('password'));
            $query = "select * from admin where username='$username' and password='$password'";
            $x = $this->db->query($query);
            if($x){
                if($x->num_rows() > 0){
                    $username = $this->input->post('username');
                    $data = array(
                                'username' => $username,
                                'is_logged_in' => 1
                            );
                    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I will appreciate any suggestion that I will get to fix this error.
I also would like to know if there is a difference of writing php codes in windows and linux OS.

by the way, here is the exact error that I am getting:
"Unable to locate the model you have specified: usersmodel"

Answer (score 0):

Its working in school because windows machine does fine with file name for `UsersModel`. Since its case insensitive.

Codeigniter is looking for UsersModel on `$this->load->model('usersModel');` line but your file name is different. Also when you load models in codeigniter its advised to use all lowercase even your class is UsersModel.

Linux is case sensitive. You should match your filename to your class name.

Comment: It should be first letter upper case only

Answer (score 0):

Your model class name should look something like

```
<?php

class Users_model extends CI_Model {  

}
```

And File Name:

```
User_model.php
```

Then when loading on to controller

```
$this->load->model('user_model');

$this->user_model->get_some_function();
```